# Error 403 found when uploading to the server

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Uploading images to Amazon S3 is working in localhost.
After deployed, it returns an error `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

I've tried [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html) but does not worked.

```
Public Sub UploadFile(filename, domainname)
        Dim keyName = filename
        Dim filePath As String = domainname + "/EmployeeImages/" + filename

        Dim client = New AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1)

        Try

            Dim wc As New WebClient
            Dim fileStream As System.IO.Stream = wc.OpenRead(filePath)
            Dim contentLength As Long = Long.Parse(wc.ResponseHeaders("Content-Length"))

            Dim request As New PutObjectRequest()
            request.BucketName = bucketName
            request.Key = keyName
            request.InputStream = fileStream
            request.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength

            client.PutObject(request)

            'WORKING BY FILE DIRECTORY
            'Dim putRequest As PutObjectRequest = New PutObjectRequest With {
            '    .BucketName = bucketName,
            '    .Key = keyName,
            '    .FilePath = filePath,
            '.ContentType = "text/plain"
            '}
            'Dim response As PutObjectResponse = client.PutObject(putRequest)
        Catch amazonS3Exception As AmazonS3Exception

            If amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode IsNot Nothing AndAlso (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") OrElse amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")) Then
                Throw New Exception("Check the provided AWS Credentials.")
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Error occurred: " & amazonS3Exception.Message)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Error occurred: " & ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

As I've said before, it works on the localhost. But not when deployed.

Comment: Most likely explanation is that you are not using the same AWS credentials to make the request, or if that is intentional, then the server credentials lack the appropriate permissions.

Comment: What do you mean the server credentials? Does being http involves in this kind of situation?

Comment: I apologize -- my comment was not as clear as it could have been.  I intended to say "server's credentials" -- I'm referring to the AWS Access Key ID or IAM role that the code on the server is using to authenticate itself, when accessing S3.  If this is different than what you are using locally, then the most likely explanation is that the two sets of credentials (local vs. server) do not have the same access rights to S3.

Comment: I have created a profile that I will use for this to run. And edited the profile name in the web.config. Should I check the profile in the server if it is added by configuring it in aws cli or not?